# Filter CSV with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to filter my CSV in `Impresiones_exchange`column with values more than 10. when I did it, I receive a new CSV (`ssss.csv`) with only a column and a True or False value. I need after `df["eCPM_a_pagar_a_medio"]` filter for values more than 10 as I said before.

```
def group():
    df = pd.read_csv('Impresiones_VIDEO.csv', sep=',')
    df = df.groupby(["Cliente","Sitio","Country"], as_index=False)['Subastas', 'Impresiones_exchange', 'Importe_a_cobrar', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio'].sum()
    df["Fill_rate"] = ((df.Impresiones_exchange / df.Subastas )* 100).round(2)
    df["eCPM_a_cobrar"] = ((df.Importe_a_cobrar / df.Impresiones_exchange )* 1000).round(2)
    df["eCPM_a_pagar_a_medio"] = ((df.Importe_a_pagar_a_medio / df.Impresiones_exchange )* 1000).round(2)
    a = df['Impresiones_exchange'] > 10
    a.to_csv('ssss.csv')
```

Comment: if one of the answers below helped, feel free too accept (tick on left) so other users can see an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Replace this line:

```
a = df['Impresiones_exchange'] > 10
```

With something like this:

```
a = df[df['Impresiones_exchange'] > 10]
```

The reason your code does not work is your `a` is set to a Boolean series. In fact, what you want is to use the Boolean series to index the dataframe.

Comment: I found this: `df.query('Impresiones_exchange>10')`. what do you think about it?

Comment: I think `df[df['Impresiones_exchange'] > 10]` is more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

With `query` I can filter the values of a csv column and take all columns!

```
def group():
    df = pd.read_csv('Impresiones_VIDEO.csv', sep=',')
    df = df.groupby(["Cliente","Sitio","Country"], as_index=False)['Subastas', 'Impresiones_exchange', 'Importe_a_cobrar', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio'].sum()
    df["Fill_rate"] = ((df.Impresiones_exchange / df.Subastas )* 100).round(2)
    df["eCPM_a_cobrar"] = ((df.Importe_a_cobrar / df.Impresiones_exchange )* 1000).round(2)
    df["eCPM_a_pagar_a_medio"] = ((df.Importe_a_pagar_a_medio / df.Impresiones_exchange )* 1000).round(2)
    df_filtered = df.query('Impresiones_exchange>10')
    df_filtered.to_csv('Impresiones_VIDEO.csv', index=False)
```